# Segue causing "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, sigabrt

i am working on a very basic application. When i try to perform a segue programatically i run into the Sigabrt error. I used an Exception Breakpoint to identify the line of code which caused the error and once i removed it the error was no longer occuring. The line of code was:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"finished" sender:self];
```

And it was embedded in the following method:

```
- (void) buttonPressed: (id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"finished" sender:self];

}
```

Please help me overcome this error as it is a very important past of my code.

Thanks, Awais

Comment: Check the console output. It should display additional information.

Comment: @fluidsonic I got the following error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'finished'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'"

Comment: Just like the error message suggests, you should create a UINavigationController and embed your view in a Navigation Controller. Or you could choose other types like Modal view, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

The thread crashing is Thread1, UI is supposed to be manipulated from Main thread which is Thread 0. Either you are triggering the segue from another thread than MainThread either you are doing something wrong on secondary thread.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out what was wrong. I had not embedded the main view Controller in a Navigation Controller. Thanks for the help.